# Want my code to convert a matrix element to a vector row by row, it only show the last row of matrix to a vector

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>

int main() {
  int i, j, matrix[2][3], vector[6];

  //filling the matrix with element
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      cin >> matrix[i][j];
  for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      cout << matrix[i][j];
    cout << endl;
  }
  //filling the vector with matrix elements
  for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      vector[j] = matrix[i][j];
  }
  //show the vector
  for(j=0;j<6;j++) {
    cout << vector[j];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
vector[j]=matrix[i][j];
```

you only use the column index (j) of the matrix element, so you write to (in order) position 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 of vector (leaving position 3 to 5 blank).

Try

```
vector[i*3 + j]=matrix[i][j];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//filling the vector with matrix elements
  for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      vector.push_back(matrix[i][j]);
  }
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.